# How to configure VMware workstation for VHD

Tags: sharepoint-2010, http-status-code-404, vmware, vhd

I am able to hook SharePoint 2010 VHD with vmware. The central admin comes up but port 80 dont even come up. I ran into this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steve_fox/archive/2010/06/15/rtm-demo-vm-for-sharepoint-amp-office-2010.aspx article but I dont know to perform this in VMWare Station 8. Please suggest.

Ping localhost host gives 127.0.0.1. But I get 404 both on localhost and 127.0.01

Ping to intranet.contoso.com takes a long time and i get request could not find host ....

Binding looks good too.

I am not seeing anything in IIS log . I mean nothing specific to intranet.contoso.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a DNS Issue to me. Try to add intranet.contoso.com to the hosts file as:

intranet.contoso.com 127.0.0.1

If this works then it is definitely a DNS issue, check if the service is running.

Also check if you actually assigned a virtual network card to the box in VMWare.

**Update**: To add NIC to VM Ware you edit machine settings and add hardware, add a network card as bridged. You can then manage the network card normally inside Windows.

Comment: My problem is that NIC setup is all messed up. What would be similar steps in VMware workstation like they have in the link above for hyper-v.